# My VBA macro is working but I need it to paste as values

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and macros.

I have used a macro to copy from one sheet and paste into another in the next available column. This is great and exactly what I want but I need it to paste as values. I have tried what everyone has said but still having no luck.

What changes do I need to make?

```
Sub HistoricalData()
Dim TargetSht As Worksheet, SourceSht As Worksheet, SourceCol As Integer, SourceCells As Range

'If an error occurs skip code to the Err-Hanlder line and the display the error message.
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'This is the sheet where your copy information from. Change "Sheet1" to the name of your soure sheet
Set SourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BARGE LIVE TRACKING")

'Name of the sheet where data is to be copied to. Rename Sheet2 to the name of your target sheet
Set TargetSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")

'This is the cells you will copy data from. This is targeting cells B1 to the last used cell in column B
Set SourceCells = SourceSht.Range("I3:I" & SourceSht.Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row)

'This is finding the next column available in the target sheet. It assumes dates will be in row 1 and data in row 2 down
If TargetSht.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
    'Cell A1 is blank so the column to put data in will be column #1 (ie A)
    SourceCol = 1
ElseIf TargetSht.Range("IV1").Value <> "" Then
    'Cell IV1 has something in it so we have reached the maximum number of columns we can use in this sheet.
    'Dont paste the data but advise'
    MsgBox "There are no more columns available in the sheet " & TargetSht.Name, vbCritical, "No More Data Can Be Copied"
    'stop the macro at this point
    Exit Sub
Else
    'cell A1 does have data and we havent reached the last column yet so find the next available column
    SourceCol = TargetSht.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
End If

'Put in the date in the appropriate column in row 1 of the target sheet
TargetSht.Cells(1, SourceCol).Value = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")

'We can now start copying data. This will copy the cells in column B from the source sheet to row 2+ in the target sheet
SourceCells.Copy TargetSht.Cells(2, SourceCol)

'Advise the user that the process was successful
MsgBox "Data copied successfully!", vbInformation, "Process Complete"

Exit Sub 'This is to stop the procedure so we dont display the error message every time.

Err_Handler:
MsgBox "The following error occured:" & vbLf & "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbLf & "Description: " & Err.Description, _
        vbCritical, "An Error Has Occured", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext


End Sub
```

Comment: did this not turn up? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx

Comment: or the comprehensive F1 help on it?

Comment: try changing `SourceCells.Copy TargetSht.Cells(2, SourceCol)` into two lines: `SourceCells.Copy` and `TargetSht.Cells(2, SourceCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule you can always record your steps with "record macro".  This is an excellent way to help you learn the ins and outs of VBA.

If you don't see the developer tab on your excel ribbon you can learn how to show it [HERE.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx)

On the developer tab click record macro.  It will ask you to name the macro but will give it a name Macro1, which is fine.  While recording, highlight the formula cells that you want to copy values from and copy (cntrl-C or right-click - Copy).

Then pick another cell to begin the paste.  Right click on that cell and choose "Paste Special."  Then choose "Values" and only the values will be pasted. Then go click Stop Recording.

Then go to your VBA editor and look for the macro in a module.  You'll find that user3598756's answer is correct.  This is a very easy way to teach yourself basic functions of excel.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. I appreciate your time and effort!